# After constraint update, when does UIView's bounds change?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

In my view controller's `viewDidLoad`, I'm adjusting a `UIImageView`'s constraints to reflect its image's aspect ratio. After it's done, I'd like to know the image view's updated bounds. The bounds *do* update in the UI, but when `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` are called (each is called only once), the bounds are still the original bounds from before I changed the aspect ratio. When should I check the bounds and make my associated changes?

Comment: Is the image view a direct subview of the view controller's `view`? Or is it more deeply nested?

Answer (score 2):

After you update the constraints in the `viewDidLoad`, update them using either one below

```
 [yourImageViewOL setNeedsDisplay];
 [yourImageViewOL layoutIfNeeded];   //Allows you to perform layout before the drawing cycle happens. -layoutIfNeeded forces layout early
```

Then you can look for the updated bounds in the `- (void)layoutSubviews;` method as this method gets called by layoutIfNeeded automatically.

> As of iOS 6.0, when constraints-based layout is used the base implementation applies the constraints-based layout, otherwise it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the method -updateViewConstraints

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];
     /// your code here
}
```